# Installing Printer: Help analysing setupapi.dev.log

Tags: windows-10, printer, setup

Been trying to install a USB Printer/Scanner.

The installation fails to effectively detect/install the Printer during the phase of the installation where I connect the Printer via its USB cable.

Does anyone here know how to effectively interpret the **setupapi.dev.log** file of the installation to determine what went wrong during the installation?

```
>>>  [Device Install (DiInstallDevice) - 
USB\VID_03F0&PID_5711&MI_02\6&1F885BE6&24&0002]
>>>  Section start 2017/10/29 12:55:41.465
  cmd: C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs
 ndv: Flags: 0x0000000a
 dvi: Class GUID of device changed to: {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}.
 sto: {Setup Import Driver Package: C:\WINDOWS\INF\oem48.inf} 12:55:41.465
 sto:      Driver package already imported as 'oem48.inf'.
 sto: {Setup Import Driver Package - exit (0x00000000)} 12:55:41.480
 dvi: Searching for hardware ID(s):
 dvi:      usb\vid_03f0&pid_5711&rev_0100&mi_02
 dvi:      usb\vid_03f0&pid_5711&mi_02
 dvi: Searching for compatible ID(s):
 dvi:      usb\class_ff&subclass_ff&prot_ff
 dvi:      usb\class_ff&subclass_ff
 dvi:      usb\class_ff
 dvi: Class GUID of device changed to: {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}.
 dvi: {Plug and Play Service: Device Install for USB\VID_03F0&PID_5711&MI_02\6&1F885BE6&24&0002}
 ndv:      Driver INF Path: C:\WINDOWS\INF\oem48.inf
 ndv:      Driver Node Name: dot4.inf:dd409bb8901a6468:DOT4USB_Inst:7.0.0.25:usb\vid_03f0&pid_5711&mi_02
 ndv:      Driver Store Path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\dot4.inf_x86_f2d3e3a3eb366a95\dot4.inf
 dvi:      Searching for hardware ID(s):
 dvi:           usb\vid_03f0&pid_5711&rev_0100&mi_02
 dvi:           usb\vid_03f0&pid_5711&mi_02
 dvi:      Searching for compatible ID(s):
 dvi:           usb\class_ff&subclass_ff&prot_ff
 dvi:           usb\class_ff&subclass_ff
 dvi:           usb\class_ff
 dvi:      Class GUID of device changed to: {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-
444553540000}.
 ndv:      {Core Device Install} 12:55:41.512
 ndv:           {Install Device - 
USB\VID_03F0&PID_5711&MI_02\6&1F885BE6&24&0002} 12:55:41.512
 ndv:                Parent device: USB\VID_03F0&PID_5711\MY7AJJ11DX04J7
 ndv:                {Configure Device - 
USB\VID_03F0&PID_5711&MI_02\6&1F885BE6&24&0002} 12:55:41.512
 ndv:                     Parent device: 
USB\VID_03F0&PID_5711\MY7AJJ11DX04J7
 ndv:                {Configure Device - exit(0x00000032)} 12:55:41.512
 dvi:                {DIF_ALLOW_INSTALL} 12:55:41.512
 dvi:                     Default installer: Enter 12:55:41.527
 dvi:                     Default installer: Exit
 dvi:                {DIF_ALLOW_INSTALL - exit(0xe000020e)} 12:55:41.527
 dvi:                {DIF_INSTALLDEVICEFILES} 12:55:41.527
 dvi:                     Default installer: Enter 12:55:41.527
 dvi:                     Default installer: Exit
 dvi:                {DIF_INSTALLDEVICEFILES - exit(0x00000000)} 
12:55:41.527
 flq:                File 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\Dot4usb.sys' pruned 
from copy.
 flq:                File 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\Dot4.sys' pruned from 
copy.
 flq:                File 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\hppldcoi.dll' pruned from 
copy.
!    sig:                GetNameSDInfo
!    sig:                Error 0: The operation completed successfully.
 flq:                Hardlinking 
'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ 
dot4.inf_x86_f2d3e3a3eb366a95\x86\difxapi.dll' to 
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\difxapi.dll'.
!!!  flq:                Error installing file (0x00000002)
!!!  flq:                Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
!    flq:                     SourceFile   - 
'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ 
dot4.inf_x86_f2d3e3a3eb366a95\x86\PortChanger.exe'
!    flq:                     TargetFile   - 
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\PortChanger.exe'
!!!  flq:                SPFQNOTIFY_COPYERROR: returned SPFQOPERATION_ABORT.
!!!  flq:                Error 1459: This operation requires an interactive 
window station.
!!!  flq:                FileQueueCommit aborting!
!!!  flq:                Error 1459: This operation requires an interactive 
window station.
!    flq:                CopyFile: 'C:\WINDOWS\Temp\OLDA207.tmp' to 

'C:\WINDOWS\system32\difxapi.dll' FAILED!
!    flq:                Error 5: Access is denied.
!    bak:                Restore attempt of 'C:\WINDOWS\Temp\OLDA207.tmp' to 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\difxapi.dll' failed (will delay restore).
!    bak:                Error 5: Access is denied.
     flq:                DeleteFile (delayed till reboot): 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLDA236.tmp'
!    ndv:                Queueing up error report since device installation failed...
     ndv:           {Install Device - exit(0x000005b3)} 12:55:41.808
     ndv:      {Core Device Install - exit(0x000005b3)} 12:55:41.808
     ump: {Plug and Play Service: Device Install exit(000005b3)}
!!!  ndv: Device install failed for device.
!!!  ndv: Error 1459: This operation requires an interactive window station.
     ndv: Installing NULL driver.
     dvi: {Plug and Play Service: Device Install for USB\VID_03F0&PID_5711&MI_02\6&1F885BE6&24&0002}
!    ndv:      Installing NULL driver!
     dvi:      {DIF_ALLOW_INSTALL} 12:55:41.933
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 12:55:41.933
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_ALLOW_INSTALL - exit(0xe000020e)} 12:55:41.933
     dvi:      {DIF_REGISTER_COINSTALLERS} 12:55:41.933
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 12:55:41.933
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_REGISTER_COINSTALLERS - exit(0x00000000)} 12:55:41.933
     dvi:      {DIF_INSTALLDEVICE} 12:55:41.933
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 12:55:41.933
!    dvi:                Installing NULL driver!
     dvi:                Install Null Driver: Removing device sub-tree. 12:55:41.933
     dvi:                Install Null Driver: Removing device sub-tree completed. 12:55:41.965
     dvi:                Install Null Driver: Restarting device. 12:55:41.965
     dvi:                Install Null Driver: Restarting device completed. 12:55:41.996
     dvi:                Install Device: Starting device. 12:55:41.996
     dvi:                Install Device: Starting device completed. 12:55:42.012
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_INSTALLDEVICE - exit(0x00000000)} 12:55:42.012
     ump: {Plug and Play Service: Device Install exit(00000000)}
<<<  Section end 2017/10/29 12:55:42.027
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0x000005b3)]


>>>  [Delete Device - USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_HP&PROD_PHOTOSMART_C4180&REV_1.00\7&894DCAC&0&MY7AJJ11DX04J7&0]
>>>  Section start 2017/10/29 13:08:07.288
      cmd: "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Temp\7zS2799\Setup\hpzpnp01.exe" -clean "/webpack" "-wStub" "2098142" -l ENU -f "C:\WINDOWS\hpoins18.dat" -Validate No -w 1442910
     dvi: Query-and-Remove succeeded
<<<  Section end 2017/10/29 13:08:07.413
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]


>>>  [Delete Device - USB\VID_03F0&PID_5711&MI_03\6&1F885BE6&24&0003]
>>>  Section start 2017/10/29 13:08:07.428
      cmd: "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Temp\7zS2799\Setup\hpzpnp01.exe" -clean "/webpack" "-wStub" "2098142" -l ENU -f "C:\WINDOWS\hpoins18.dat" -Validate No -w 1442910
     dvi: Query-and-Remove succeeded
<<<  Section end 2017/10/29 13:08:07.428
<<<  [Exit status: SUCCESS]
```

Your assistance is very much appreciated. Been trying to get this to install correctly for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1459: This operation requires an interactive window station.

Also the log provides Access is denied.

It could be related to your account. (admin account and system account)

Turn off firewall/AV for a few minutes

Go to each of the following folders, right click them, and click the new Take Ownership option (created by the above):

C:\Windows\system32/drivers

C:\Windows\system32/driverstore

C:\Windows\system32/DRVSTORE

Then right click on each folder, Advanced, and set Full Control for all the accounts shown.

Comment: Do you mean the Take Ownership Third-Party download for Windows? Also, I keep getting "Failed to enumerate object in the container. Access Is Denied" messages when altering Security Permissions on the above folders.